# Resample rasters after buffering in R

Tags: raster, r, buffer, clip, masking

I have a raster stack that has NULL values from applying a focal buffer. They're not `NA` values but `0`. Each layer shares the same extent, but the layers with the larger buffer widths have more `0` values (more whitespace around the perimeter) than those with smaller buffer widths. How can I create a new stack that clips each layer based on the extent of the largest buffer layer after removing these `0` values? In other words, I would like the extent of each layer to match the smallest extent after removing `0` values. In the example below, the `X2017.10.10.arterial10000m` layer would have the smallest extent.

[image]

Comment: Do zeroes occur elsewhere in the layers, or are they only ever present as a border of zeroes round your data? Because its a lot easier to eventually construct a mask if you know there's no zeroes anywhere else except the border. Unless R has a "greedy crop" function that can trim the edges of rasters.... Let's go read some documentation...

Comment: Yes, I've realized that some of the layers have zeroes within the actual data (and not just outside the desired extent). For now, I'm working on cropping using a new layer that has the correct extent. I think I'm onto something! Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Okay, I'm thinking of the raster "trim" function. I think if you `trim` all your layers then crop by the smallest resulting layer, or crop by all of them because the smallest will "win"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some raster stack with white (zero) borders, `s`:

```
> plot(s)
```

[image]

Note the first layer has no border, the second a wide border, and the third a narrow one-pixel border.

Construct a list of trimmed layers, `mm` - note this is not a stack because the extents are now different:

```
> mm = lapply(unstack(s),trim,values=0)
```

Make a copy of `s`:

```
> ss = s
```

And now crop it to each of the masks. The smallest mask wins:

```
> for(i in 1:length(mm)){ss = crop(ss, mm[[i]])}
> plot(ss)
```

[image]

Note the layers all look the same because I created them from the same random matrix.

Instead of cropping with all the layers it should suffice to just find the layer with the smallest extent and crop by that one only.

Comment: This is working with my data too. Does it make sense that the extent of `ss` is the same as `s`?

Comment: no, because it should have trimmed it. For my test, extent(s) is 0,1,0,1 and extent(ss) is 0.125,.875,.1666,.8333

Comment: Strange, I'm still getting the same extent with my data. The plotted output of each of my layers looks correct, but the extent has not changed.